# Different output of EMV session key using BP-Tool and UL testing tool

Tags: java, encryption, emv, mastercard

I am now running **M-TIP** test case  using **UL Test Tools**. I tried to calculate cryptogram via BP-Tools-Cryptographic Calculator `(EMV -> Application Cryptograms -> MasterCard)`. According to EMV Book 2 and online sources, the process should be generate UDK using ICC Master Key first and then generate a session key. I find that is different session key output from BP-Tools and UL Testing Tools.

**BP-Tools**

```
MDK: 9E15204313F7318ACB79B90BD986AD29  
PAN: 5413330089020011  
PAN seq: 03
```

`Option A` `Odd Parity`

***Output: 4519028F544CAD6DCEE9A7C7C17562FD***

**UL Testing Tools**

ICC Master Key AC:               9E 15 20 43 13 F7 31 8A CB 79 B9 0B D9 86 AD 29
Derived Card Unique Key:         45 19 02 8F 54 4C AD 6D CE E9 A7 C7 C1 75 62 FD

**The UDK outputs from both BP and UL tools are matched.**

However when generate session key,

**BP-Tools**

```
UDK: 4519028F544CAD6DCEE9A7C7C17562FD  
ATC: 0027  
Unpredictable Number: C4801420
```

***Output: 2086DFADD5891345897A5BAEDA6ED9F7***

**UL Testing Tools**

Derived Session Key:             21 87 DE AC D4 89 12 45 89 7A 5A AE DA 6E D8 F7

**The session key are `different` even same UDK is used.**

Can someone please provides some insight on the question above, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Where did you get the tool? I see it says it's free but I don't see the Download!

Answer (score 1):

The results of both the  EFTLAB's Crypto Calculator and UL Tools are the same. But the Crypto Calc is adjusting the parity on the key and UL Tools is not.

When you take UL's result and run it through the Crypto Calc > Keys > Keys DES/TDES/AES > [tab] Parity Enforcement - odd parity setting, you'll actually get the same result.

> [2021-07-21 01:10:35] Keys: Key parity enforcement finished
>
> ---
>
> Key:             2187DEACD4891245897A5AAEDA6ED8F7
> Key length:      32
> Parity enforced: Odd
> New key:         2086DFADD5891345897A5BAEDA6ED9F7

All consequent key usages in MasterCard's EMV require the odd parity to be applied. Why is UL Tool not adjusting parity of the resulting key? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Session key calculation based on the transaction data as the ATC, UN in some algorithm cases.

Check that you have same input transaction data for the session key calculation in both tools.